# Transaction error on running report in test codeunit

Tags: automated-tests, dynamics-al

When i run any report in the test codeunits via the al test tool i get a transction error:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI54F.png)

the error happens when in anyway when a report is run.
in the current version of the code it is trigger by Report.RunRequestPage

```
Subtype = Test;
TestPermissions = Disabled;
EventSubscriberInstance = Manual;
InherentPermissions = X;

[Test]
[HandlerFunctions('CalculatePlanReportRequestPageHandler30D')]
[CommitBehavior(CommitBehavior::Ignore)]
[TransactionModel(TransactionModel::AutoCommit)]
procedure CreateRequestionNone()
var
    ReqLine: Record "Requisition Line";
    ReqWorksheet: TestPage "Req. Worksheet";
    CalculatePlan: Report "Calculate Plan - Req. Wksh.";
    "Req. Wksh. Template": record "Req. Wksh. Template";
    "Requisition Wksh. Name": Record "Requisition Wksh. Name";
    Fail: Boolean;
    Succes: Boolean;
    XmlParameters: Text;
begin

    //[Scenario] A Requisition for an item is made
    //[Given] An item for a customer a vendor and a  Salesorder
    PrepareSetupEnabled();
    PrepareData();

    //[WHEN] when a Requisition is made
    //ReqWorksheet.OpenView();
    //    Commit();


    if "Req. Wksh. Template".FindFirst() then begin
        "Requisition Wksh. Name".setrange("Worksheet Template Name", "Req. Wksh. Template".Name);
        if "Requisition Wksh. Name".FindFirst() then;
    end;
    CalculatePlan.SetTemplAndWorksheet("Req. Wksh. Template".Name, "Requisition Wksh. Name".Name);
    XmlParameters := Report.RunRequestPage(Report::"Calculate Plan - Req. Wksh.");
    LibraryReportDataset.RunReportAndLoad(Report::"Calculate Plan - Req. Wksh.", ReqLine, XmlParameters);
    // CalculatePlan.Run;
    Clear(CalculatePlan);
    //  ReqWorksheet.CalculatePlan.Invoke();
    ReqLine.SetRange("No.", '150.160.170');
    ReqLine.FindFirst();
    ReqWorksheet.GoToRecord(ReqLine);
    CarryOutActionMessage(ReqWorksheet);

    Succes := false;
    ReqLine.SetRange("No.", '150.160.170');
    if ReqLine.FindSet() then
        repeat
            if not (ReqLine."Planning Flexibility" = ReqLine."Planning Flexibility"::None) then
                Fail := true;
        until ReqLine.Next() = 0;

    if not Fail then
        Succes := true;


    //[THEN] then an a succesfull Procces should have happend;
    Assert.IsTrue(Succes, 'The Requisition should have been succesfull');
end;
```

The eventual purpose of this codeunit is to test out calculate plan of Requisition Worksheets.
Is there any solution to this problem?